# Strange infinite loop in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, infinite-loop

//Nevermind, it seems some of the testing code of my university seemed to create an infinite loop when I didnt have all methods that were part of the task implemented...

Hi guys I know this might seem a bit lazy, but the java compiler of my university claims that I have an infinite loop in my Code and I cant find it! Here's the code:

```
public class List {
    private class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node next;

        private Node(int element) {
            this.value = element;
            next = null;
        }

        private boolean hasNext(){
            return next != null;
        }

        private void setNext(Node n){
            next = n;
        }

        private Node getNext(){
            return next;
        }

        private int getElement(){
            return value;
        }

    }

    private static void flip(Node first, Node second) {
        int tmp = first.value;
        first.value = second.value;
        second.value = tmp;
    }

    private Node head;

    public List() {
        head = null;
    }

    public void add(int e){
        if(head == null){
            head = new Node(e);
        }else{
            Node n = head;
            while(n.hasNext()){
                n = n.getNext();
            }
            n.setNext(new Node(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Node n = head;
        String s = "";
        while(n != null){
            s += n.getElement() + " ";
            n = n.getNext();

        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

I basically need to program a list of integers, which seems easy to me, but already at the part of adding elements I get this error...

Comment: `while(n != null)` and then you do nothing inside the loop that will modify n and turn it to null at some point. Seems pretty straight forward and not mysterious at all.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS ah, yeah thanks! Sadly that still doesnt change the output of the Compiler

Comment: "that still doesnt change the output of the Compiler" can we see the exact output you are seeing? Also be sure that you used corrected code.

Comment: @Pshemo Original: "Zeitgrenze überschritten: Ihr Programm beinhaltet vermutlich eine Endlosschleife" Translated that would mean that there COULD be an infinite loop, but the only definitive answer that I have is that the program timed out. (We work in a browser enviroment... I dont know any more specific details)

Comment: Your code looks ok. Please provide an example (where you clearly show how you create and set up a List object) where it fails.

Comment: @Stefan that is my problem. I dont specifically run the code. we have a website that we program in and then press on turn in and the website determines how good we did the task by testing the code(I guess specifically by running the methods that we programmed)

Comment: Maybe try to and synchronized to the ass method?

Comment: Problem could be caused by fact that your list doesn't remember *last* node after which next data should be added. Because of that in `add` method you are required to loop from start each time you want to add new element which means that: 1st element would require 1 step, 2nd element would require 2 steps, etc. So to add N element you will need `1+2+3+...N = (1+N)*N/2` steps which is `O(N^2)` complexity which for large N may take quite long time (which reminds infinite loop).

Comment: is it solved (as the title hints that it is solved )?

Comment: @Golu yup, i didnt know how to set it as solved properly, sorry

Comment: You can post the answer yourself and accept it.(Generally SO allows to accept the answer after 2 days of posting your answer)